# Extract one or more patterns from a string

Tags: bash, command-line

I have some lines which look like:

```
function( "((2 * VAR(\"xxx\")) - VAR(\"yyy\"))" ?name "name" ?plot t ?save t ?evalType 'point)
function("value(res VAR(\"zzz\"))" ?name "othername" ?plot t ?save t ?evalType 'point)
```

And, I would like to find a command which would output the string defined in the VAR function, i.e. something like:

```
xxx yyy
zzz
```

I have tried in `sed` but as I understand I have no way to do it in a non-greedy way.

Comment: I am new to the site and I was wondering why this has been downvoted. Did I maybe choose improper wording? I'd like to know how I could improve the question phrasing if this is the case

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvoted (you gave input and expected output, which is very useful, and which many first-time askers omit doing). Perhaps posting the code that you tried and why its output is not what you want would have been better-received?

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I thought my attempt to be so "pathetic" that it was not even worth mentioning. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I'm also slightly confused you got downvoted, particularly quite that many times. Unfortunately, none of the downvoters appear to have deemed it necessary to write a comment stating what they didn't like (doing so is generally a good practice). The only thing I can think of is that your question is extremely specific (for a very particular input, produce a very particular output) and unlikely to help any other users in the future. Perhaps a more general formulation would have been preferable  ("How can I extract substrings identified by a particular context in a string?" or similar).

Comment: I am confused as well. I'll  try to improve on formulating future possible questions (or answers) in a more generic way then.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be afraid to ask specific questions. :) But the way I would have formulated it would probably have asked the question in a more generic way first, and then: "Specifically, I would like to do the following...". Anyhow, just my 2 cents. I didn't downvote you. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `grep` that supports Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) then you can use

```
grep -Po 'VAR\(\\"\K[^\\]*'
```

or (more symmetrically - using lookbehind and lookahead)

```
grep -Po '(?<=VAR\(\\").*?(?=\\")'
```

Ex.

```
$ grep -Po 'VAR\(\\"\K[^\\]*'
function( "((2 * VAR(\"xxx\")) - VAR(\"yyy\"))" ?name "name" ?plot t ?save t ?evalType 'point)
function("value(res VAR(\"zzz\"))" ?name "othername" ?plot t ?save t ?evalType 'point)
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

Ex.

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=VAR\(\\").*?(?=\\")'
function( "((2 * VAR(\"xxx\")) - VAR(\"yyy\"))" ?name "name" ?plot t ?save t ?evalType 'point)
function("value(res VAR(\"zzz\"))" ?name "othername" ?plot t ?save t ?evalType 'point)
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks. I was indeed thinking that perl was somehow the way to go (because of the "lazy" matching), even thoough I never used it

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a regex like grep. Something like `grep 'VAR\("[A-z0-9]*"\)'` However, it won't work in you case with all those \"s. Maybe something along the lines `grep '(^VAR(\")[A-z0-9](^\"))' | grep 'VAR\(\\"[A-z0-9]*\\"\)'`

I haven't been using grep for long either. :)

Comment: I think there is some error in there, I suspect some escaping? Do you think that this expression would be a "non-greedy" matching?